# Count number of values per id

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's assume I have table1:

```
id  value1  value2 value3
1   z       null    null
1   z       null    null
1   null    y       null
1   null    null    x
2   null    y       null
2   z       null    null 
3   null    y       null
3   null    null    null 
3   z       null    null
```

and I have table2:

```
    id  
    1  
    2  
    3
```

I want to count number of values in each column per id to have output like this.
(ex. id 1 has 2 - z's, one y and one x)

```
 id value1 value2  value3  
  1   2     1      1     
  2   1      1     0   
  3   1      1     0
```

What approach would be suggested?

I am currently using Oracle 12c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `COUNT` (which only counts non-null values):

```
select id,
       count(value1) as value1,
       count(value2) as value2,
       count(value3) as value3
from table1
group by id
```

**Edit**:

If values are not null but '.' (or something else), do use `case` expressions to do conditional counting, something like:

```
select id,
       count(case when value1 <> '.' then 1 end) as value1,
       count(case when value2 <> '.' then 1 end) as value2,
       count(case when value3 <> '.' then 1 end) as value3
from table1
group by id
```

Comment: thanks. what would be suggested if  values are not null but '.' or something else?