# SAS: Need to count number of instances per id

Tags: sql, count, sas, unique, distinct-values

Let's assume I have table1:

```
id  value1  value2 value3
1   z       null    null
1   z       null    null
1   null    y       null
1   null    null    x
2   null    y       null
2   z       null    null 
3   null    y       null
3   null    null    null 
3   z       null    null


id  value1  value2 value3
1   z       null    null
1   z       null    null
1   null    y       null
1   null    null    x
2   null    y       null
2   z       null    null 
3   null    y       null
3   null    null    null 
3   z       null    null
```

and I have table2:

```
id  
1  
2  
3
```

I want to count number of values in each column per id to have output like this. (ex. id 1 has 2 - z's, one y and one x)

```
 id value1 value2  value3  
  1   2      1      1     
  2   1      1      0   
  3   1      1      0
```

Need to do this in SAS. There is an example of this in Oracle but not in SAS.

Comment: oracle solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057894/count-number-of-values-per-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a simple query using proc sql.  For all the ids in the first table:

```
proc sql;
    select id, count(val1) as val1, count(val2) as val2, count(val3 as val3)
    from table1
    group by id;
run;
```

`count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values in a column or expression.